# Regex / grep match on: "not this" and "that"

Tags: regex, grep, regex-negation

From a Linux command line, I would like to find all the instances in multiple files where I do not reference a figure reference with `Fig.`.

So I'm looking each line for when I don't preface `\ref{fig` with exactly `Fig.` .

1. `Fig. \ref{fig:myFigure}`
2. `A sentence with Fig. \ref{fig:myFigure} there.`
3. `\ref{fig:myFigure}`
4. `A sentence with \ref{fig:myFigure} there.`

The regex should ignore cases (1) and (2), but find cases (3) and (4).

Comment: What about linebreaks between `Fig.` and `\ref`?

Comment: @BenjaminW. - yes that is a possibility. I omitted it from the original post to concentrate on the regex required for a "not this" and "that".  The optional linebreak won't be difficult to add.

Comment: The optional linebreak makes a big difference, as grep looks at files line by line. If you tell it to use another character instead of newline, like the null character, a match will return the whole file as it is considered a single line.

Comment: This is true.  Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Negative Lookahead like:

```
^((?!Fig\. {0,1}\\ref\{fig).)*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/wSw9iI/2

```
Negative Lookahead (?!Fig\.\s*\\ref\{fig)
Assert that the Regex below does not match
Fig matches the characters Fig literally (case sensitive)
\. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
\s* matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\\ matches the character \ literally (case sensitive)
ref matches the characters ref literally (case sensitive)
\{ matches the character { literally (case sensitive)
fig matches the characters fig literally (case sensitive)
```